# Apache Superset : sqllab - Results backend isn’t configured

Tags: apache-superset

I am running superset on docker and created new mssql database connection and able to view schemas , tables and preview the table in SQLlab
however , now able to run the sql queries . I am getting following error “Results backend isn’t configured.”
can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of error you'd get when trying to run an async query but the Results backend for your Celery workers isn't configured properly.
The easiest way to double check this is the issue, and get your query working, is to go back into your database configuration in superset, and set async processing off: navigate to Source > Databases > [click on the DB you want to run the query against] and check off "Asynchronous Query Execution".
You should then be able to run your query. 
To setup Celery workers for real, see the instructions at https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#celery-tasks